# How to save this image to MySQL database using HIbernate as BLOB?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, blob

How can I save this uploaded image to MySQL database using Hibernate?  Do I need to convert this image to byte array or is there any other way to do this?

```
try {
    // parses the request's content to extract file data
    List formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
    Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();

    // iterates over form's fields
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
        // processes only fields that are not form fields
        if (!item.isFormField()) {
            String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
            String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
            File storeFile = new File(filePath);

            System.out.println("Image file name is :" + fileName);

            // saves the file on disk
            item.write(storeFile);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent mapping type for Blob in Java for MySQL is `byte[]`. You should use the corresponding dialect in Hibernate and annotate a property something like

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "data", columnDefinition = "blob", length = 16777215)
public byte[] getData() {
  return this.data;
}
```

Comment: First do I need to convert this image to byte ?  or is there any other way ?

Comment: I've used `byte[] fileData = FileUtil.getBytes(file);`

Comment: If you use Struts it directly stores files to the action bean, you don't need to maze with other frameworks like commons-fileupload.

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo example please go through it and ask if any problem u have

https://github.com/loiane/hibernate-image-example

explanation of above example:

https://dzone.com/articles/how-load-or-save-image-using